# Display Script in Header When URL Variable Present

Tags: functions, javascript

I have a script that I want to display in the wp_head, but only if a URL variable is passed. For example, if someone visits https://example.com/?feedback=yes I want the following script to display:

```
  <script>
    alert( 'Hello, world!' );
  </script>
```

I can already have this display all the time via the following function, but it's the part around having it only display if that URL variable exists that I'm not sure on.

```
/* Describe what the code snippet does so you can remember later on */
add_action('wp_head', 'your_function_name');
function your_function_name(){
?>
  <script>
    alert( 'Hello, world!' );
  </script>
<?php
};
```

Answer (score 0):

URL variables like that are stored in the `$_GET` variable. You can check the existence and value of one like this:

```
add_action(
    'wp_head',
    function() {
        if ( isset( $_GET['feedback'] ) && 'yes' === $_GET['feedback'] ) {
            ?>
            <script>
                alert( 'Hello, world!' );
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
);
```

The check for `isset()` is necessary as checking `$_GET['feedback']` alone will throw an error if it's not present in the URL at all.

Comment: That was the answer. Thanks Jacob!